# Eclipse Scout check when leave page

Tags: eclipse, treenode, savechanges, eclipse-scout

I am writing a scout application, and I stumbled upon some problem. 
In my standard Outline I have more than one page. In page A I have some editable table with save button. What is in page B is not important for this discussion.

```
Outline
   page A
   page B
```

If page A is selected and I edit some data I would like to be notified if I click on page B that some data are not saved.

So before Outline switch between page A and B I would like to have control to not switch to page B because same data in A are not saved.

I have actually solve this problem with extending pages, but I an looking if there is some standard pre-defined way for this.

Comment: The only method I can think of is the `setPageChangeStrategy` on your `AbstractOutline`. There you can prevent the page from actually being changed, but I don't know how to prevent the node being selected in the tree. Ideally you would want to intercept the event *before* the user selects the new page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent the node selection from really happening. As you mentioned, you can listen for activation and deactivation events in your Page by overriding the methods `execPageActivated`and `execPageDeactivated`, respectively. But by using this approach, you cannot take control over node switching.

A bit more of control you get by providing your own implementation of `createPageChangeStrategy` in your Outline class by injecting a custom `DefaultPageChangeStrategy`. So you get informed every time a node change happens with a respective pageChange event. As long as your page is invalid, you prevent the page switching from happening and restore the origin tree selection.

Please take a look at the following example:

```
@Override
IPageChangeStrategy createPageChangeStrategy() {
    return new DefaultPageChangeStrategy() {

      @Override
      public void pageChanged(IOutline outline, IPage deselectedPage, IPage selectedPage) {
        if (deselectedPage instanceof APage && !((APage) deselectedPage).isValid()) { // #isValid is your check method for validity.
          // Do not propagate the PageChangeEvent and restore the selection of the invalid page.

          // Uninstall the PageChangeStrategy to ignore the event of restoring the selection.
          final IPageChangeStrategy pageChangeStrategy = this;
          setPageChangeStrategy(null);

          // Restore the selection and install the PageChangeStrategy anew.
          new ClientSyncJob("Restore node selection", ClientSession.get()) {

            @Override
            protected void runVoid(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws Throwable {
              YourOutline.this.selectNode(deselectedPage);
              setPageChangeStrategy(pageChangeStrategy);
            }
          }.schedule();
        }
        else {
          super.pageChanged(outline, deselectedPage, selectedPage);
        }
      }
    };
  }
```